# How to show data from database with jquery?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

its my first week learn jquery and
i use this jquery to insert multiple rows on my page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var count = 0;

        $("#add_btn").click(function(){
                count += 1;
            $('#container').append(
                         '<tr class="records">'
                     + '<td ><div id="'+count+'">' + count + '</div></td>'
                     + '<td><input id="task_' + count + '" name="task_' + count + '" type="text"></td>'
                     + '<td><input id="person_' + count + '" name="person_' + count + '" type="text"></td>'
                     + '<td><input id="time_' + count + '" name="time_' + count + '" type="text"></td>'
                     + '<td><a class="remove_item" href="#" >Delete</a>'
                     + '<input id="rows_' + count + '" name="rows[]" value="'+ count +'" type="hidden"></td></tr>'
                );
            });

            $(".remove_item").live('click', function (ev) {
            if (ev.type == 'click') {
            $(this).parents(".records").fadeOut();
                    $(this).parents(".records").remove();
        }
        });
    });
```

this how i load jquery on my page

```
<table>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="button" name="add_btn" value="Add" id="add_btn"></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>No</td><td>Task</td><td>Person Responsible</td><td>Due Date</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="container">

    </tbody>
    <tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

but i want change the person row`'<td><input id="person_' + count + '" name="person_' + count + '" type="text"></td>'` to show the list data of person from my database

can someone give me example how to do that?
i using codeigniter to build this

Comment: First try to make an ajax call to your controller's method. and then append that data to the table cell.

Comment: @ArunJain can you give some example sir?

Comment: http://www.w3cgallery.com/w3c-blog/php-mysql-ajax-hacks-trick/ajax-fetch-records-by-phpmysql-with-pagination. Hope this will help you till some extent. I am finding a perfect solution for you. BRB

Comment: This link will surely help you. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jquery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) (or $.ajax(), see example) to make a call to a method on your server. The requested method on your server collects the data from the database and pass it on to the jquery.get() function. If the data you return is in json format, you can use [jquery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead.